# Parsing help in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, parsing

i'm not exactly sure how to word this question nor how to do it so I figured I would come here for some insight. So, What is a query program that runs a command and gets the return data this data comes back to look like this.

```
[0]: 
    ServerId: 1
    ServerPort: 9987
    ServerStatus: Online
[1]: 
    ServerId: 13
    ServerPort: 4000
    ServerStatus: Online
[2]: 
    ServerId: 14
    ServerPort: 4001
    ServerStatus: Online
[3]: 
    ServerId: 15
    ServerPort: 4002
    ServerStatus: Online
[4]: 
    ServerId: 16
    ServerPort: 4003
    ServerStatus: Online
[5]: 
    ServerId: 17
    ServerPort: 4004
    ServerStatus: Online
[6]: 
    ServerId: 18
    ServerPort: 4005
    ServerStatus: Online
[7]: 
    ServerId: 19
    ServerPort: 42069
    ServerStatus: Online
[8]: 
    ServerId: 20
    ServerPort: 4006
    ServerStatus: Online
[9]: 
    ServerId: 21
    ServerPort: 5022
    ServerStatus: Online
[10]: 
    ServerId: 23
    ServerPort: 4007
    ServerStatus: Online
[11]: 
    ServerId: 24
    ServerPort: 4008
    ServerStatus: None
[12]: 
    ServerId: 25
    ServerPort: 4009
    ServerStatus: Online
[13]: 
    ServerId: 26
    ServerPort: 4010
    ServerStatus: Online
[14]: 
    ServerId: 27
    ServerPort: 4011
    ServerStatus: Online
[15]: 
    ServerId: 28
    ServerPort: 4012
    ServerStatus: Online
```

Now there will not only be 15 servers its changeable and could go to any amount. How would I go about pulling the data from each of little, oh how would you say it, snippets of info? Into a list box in order from smallest to largest, 0 first to what ever comes after. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
[0]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 56
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 10000
    ServerUptime: 18.05:22:01
    ServerName: The FourHorsemens & The Disciples
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 1
    ServerPort: 9987
    ServerStatus: Online
[1]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 0
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 10
    ServerUptime: 18.15:03:24
    ServerName: NotYoda
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 13
    ServerPort: 4000
    ServerStatus: Online
[2]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 0
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 10
    ServerUptime: 18.15:03:24
    ServerName: CYNTEX HF - TS3 Server :D
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 14
    ServerPort: 4001
    ServerStatus: Online
[3]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 0
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 10
    ServerUptime: 18.15:03:24
    ServerName: GuyCheap
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 15
    ServerPort: 4002
    ServerStatus: Online
[4]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 0
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 10
    ServerUptime: 18.15:03:24
    ServerName: Game All Day
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 16
    ServerPort: 4003
    ServerStatus: Online
[5]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 0
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 10
    ServerUptime: 18.15:03:24
    ServerName: #Cloud9
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 17
    ServerPort: 4004
    ServerStatus: Online
[6]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 0
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 50
    ServerUptime: 18.15:03:24
    ServerName: FuryTech
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 18
    ServerPort: 4005
    ServerStatus: Online
[7]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 3
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 100
    ServerUptime: 11.18:18:51
    ServerName: Frost-Hosting - A Teamspeak Hosting Service
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 19
    ServerPort: 42069
    ServerStatus: Online
[8]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 0
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 10
    ServerUptime: 18.15:03:24
    ServerName: Hangout
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 20
    ServerPort: 4006
    ServerStatus: Online
[9]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 0
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 10
    ServerUptime: 18.14:56:17
    ServerName: stevenwitha4.6@gmail.com's_Teamspeak_Server!
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 21
    ServerPort: 5022
    ServerStatus: Online
[10]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 0
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 10
    ServerUptime: 17.20:32:39
    ServerName: Straight Flush Gaming
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 23
    ServerPort: 4007
    ServerStatus: Online
[11]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 
    ServerUptime: 
    ServerName: 1r6ddyce@gmail.com
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 24
    ServerPort: 4008
    ServerStatus: None
[12]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 1
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 10
    ServerUptime: 13.01:01:34
    ServerName: Welcome to Gaming Room - by Anders & Christian
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 25
    ServerPort: 4009
    ServerStatus: Online
[13]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 3
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 10
    ServerUptime: 12.21:46:55
    ServerName: Reineling's teamspeak
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 26
    ServerPort: 4010
    ServerStatus: Online
[14]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 0
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 10
    ServerUptime: 12.00:04:56
    ServerName: CrashGFX
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 27
    ServerPort: 4011
    ServerStatus: Online
[15]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 0
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 10
    ServerUptime: 12.00:03:52
    ServerName: XBL Hammer
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 28
    ServerPort: 4012
    ServerStatus: Online
[16]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 0
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 50
    ServerUptime: 7.18:43:07
    ServerName: Team Battles!
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 29
    ServerPort: 10000
    ServerStatus: Online
[17]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 0
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 100
    ServerUptime: 6.19:17:32
    ServerName: YoloMcSwagins
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 30
    ServerPort: 4013
    ServerStatus: Online
[18]: 
    UniqueId: 
    ServerNumberOfClientsOnline: 0
    ServerNumberOfQueryClientsOnline: 0
    ServerMaximumClientsAllowed: 20
    ServerUptime: 6.19:16:30
    ServerName: -Cybia-
    ServerAutoStart: True
    ServerMachineId: 
    ServerId: 31
    ServerPort: 4014
    ServerStatus: Online
```

Comment: you need to add some detail - where does the list come from, for starters?  Are you polling something? is it a file? you seem to be asking how to get that data (`gets the return data`) -- how would we know? **And** asking how to parse it.

Comment: The data comes from a query response via telnet, I just need to convert the text that I provided into ListBox items @Plutonix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can make a function like this:

```
Private Shared Function GetResults(match As String) As Dictionary(Of [String], [String])
    Dim num = Regex.Match(match, "\[(\d+)\]").Groups(0).Value 'Gets the ID of the entry
    Dim allIds = Regex.Matches(match, "(\w+): (.+)") 'Gets each key/value
    Dim dictionary = New Dictionary(Of [String], [String])()

    dictionary.Add("Index", num)
    For Each i As Match In allIds
        dictionary.Add(i.Groups(1).Value, i.Groups(2).Value)
    Next
    Return dictionary
End Function
```

And then maybe call it like this:

```
Dim reg = Regex.Matches(yourValue, "\[\d*\]:(\s+\w+:.+){1,}") 'yourValue is all of the servers
Dim allEntries = (From i As Match In reg Select GetResults(i.Value)).ToList()
```

Comment: I appreciate the comment testing it now.

Comment: After some testing I haven't managed to get this working, how would I go about extracting all of the strings from each collection inside of Results? @Dom Stepek

Comment: Ok so let's say you want to get the ServerPort of the first one, I presume server, you would could call it like: MsgBox(allEntries(0)("ServerPort")) which shows '9987' @Killpot

Comment: How would I go about doing the exact same thing here but instead on only 3 lines of info, there is 11? Like what I have added to the bottom of the original post.

Comment: Change `Dim reg = Regex.Matches(YOUR_VALUE, "\[\d*\]:(\s+\w+: \w+){3}")` to `Dim reg = Regex.Matches(YOUR_VALUE, "\[\d*\]:(\s+\w+: \w+){11}")`

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work even after changing what you said to change, I've updated the bottom of the post with what im trying to parse. What you originally said works with the first message but I also need to parse this message too. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Try changing what I previously said to change with `Dim reg = Regex.Matches(YOUR_VALUE, "\[\d*\]:(\s+\w+:.+){1,}")`

Comment: It seems to only grab info before a space, for example if the name of the server is "Test Server" it will only come back with "Test".

Comment: Alright I upgraded the code so that it works with spaces and everything else that you needed. The problem was that in the GetResults() Function it was looking for [word: word] not [word: allCharacters]. @Killpot